# How could I fix these broken RSS head links in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: html, css, joomla, rss, joomla2.5

I am in this weird situation where the links to RSS in a page appear wrongly formatted.

The page is a job search tool in a company. In lines 12 and 13 you can see the links are

```
<link href="/index.php/bolsa-trabajo/rss/1?type=rss?format=feed" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Todas las categorías Feed (RSS)" />
```

and

```
<link href="/index.php/bolsa-trabajo/rss/1?type=atom?format=feed" rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Todas las categorías Feed (Atom)" />
```

Well, the second parameter `format=feed`is after a `?` which makes the server respond with 500.

I've been searching and researching for days now, and I have found no similar problem on the net. I have not got much knowledge about Joomla but I have walked through many different files on the server and couldn't find the solution.

The site is using the template `rt_ionosphere` by `RocketTheme` and the module `jobboard` by `Tandolin`. `Joomla` version is `2.5.9`.

Comment: Current version is 2.5.11. Try installing Joomla on a clean install and replicating the problem. It is not clear to me how does the link get generated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Trying a clean install will probably solve that and other problems, but it's a corporate site and cannot do that at the moment. I've been thinking and could I possibly hack it down with a .htaccess rewrite spell? I've tried different possibilities but the language seems to be very obscure.

Comment: If you can't isolate the problem, it's hard to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in Tandolin's Job Board for Joomla component. I had to modify `components/com_jobboard/views/list/tmpl/default_list.php` and `components/com_jobboard/views/jobboard/tmpl/default.php`. There I hardcoded the '`&`' substituted for the variable `$feedPrefix`.